# Como renombro un valor en QListView?

Tags: c++, qt

No entiendo mucho como funcionan las funciones de cpp que tiene, hasta ahora pude crear nuevos datos en la lista y eliminarlos, pero al querer renombrarlos me confundo

```
void MainWindow::on_BotonAnadir_clicked()
{
    int row = model->rowCount();
    model->insertRows(row,1);
    QModelIndex index = model->index(row);
    ui->listView->setCurrentIndex(index);
    ui->listView->edit(index);
}


void MainWindow::on_BotonRemover_clicked()
{
    model->removeRows(ui->listView->currentIndex().row(),1);
}
```

```
model->setData(ui->listView->currentIndex(),"");
```

Eso tengo, pero me cambia el valor desde el codigo y lo ideal seria hacerlo desde la ventana

Comment: El valor has de cambiarlo en el modelo, que es el que "alimenta" al QListView. Habría que ver cómo lo tienes implementado. Te paso este enlace, por si no lo habías mirado: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

Comment: Lamentablemente mi nivel de ingles es bastante bajo, he aprendido por leer cosas basicas y traductor de google

Comment: ¿Puedes poner cómo tienes implementado el modelo?